# CSV column heading isn't showing up in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, csv

I am looking to import the following CSV file (PIC1) using pandas so that I can ultimately drop all rows that correspond to Alaska FIPS codes (02000-02999), but when I try to read out the FIPS column heading I encounter the following issue. (PIC2).

I am incredibly new to python/pandas and coding in general, so any direction is greatly appreciated?

[PIC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKeXZ.jpg)
[PIC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwNrl.jpg)

I have tried researching the issue online but to no avail.

Comment: Add argument `skipinitialspace=True` to `read_csv`. Currently the column name is " FIPS" with a space at beginning.

Comment: what you get when runs `print(df.columns)` ? maybe there are spaces in column name `FIPS`

Answer (score 1):

Add this after reading the `csv` file to remove the spaces in all the headers:

`df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: Ok! I did so and I think this works now. thank you, and doing so will remove the commas and allow the headers to "fit" in a readable way for the data frame? trying to understand for my own learning

Comment: @RohanSharma The examples you show, indicate that all of your columns except "Record" starts with a space.  So when you call for "FIPS", python can't find it because it is actually reading it as " FIPS". The code above is replacing all of the spaces (' ') with no space (''). You could avoid this altogether if you are able to remove the leading spaces in the original workbook.